# SSL error/warning on Android handest but not on Desktop browser

Tags: android, apache, ssl, centos, ssl-certificate

When I browse to my site on Chrome on my desktop going to https://eightpointnine.com I don't get a problem but when I go to the same URL on my android handset using the Chrome browser (or the default browser) I get an error telling me the certificate isn't from a trusted authority (it's from globalsign). Any ideas what I have done wrong?

I'm running an Apache Server I have a virtual host with "SSLCertificateChainFile" mentioned in it if that helps track down the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: A certificate can contain a special *Authority Information Access* extension ([RFC-3280](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3280)) with URL to issuer's certificate. Most browsers can use the AIA extension to download missing intermediate certificate to complete the certificate chain. But some clients (mobile browsers, OpenSSL) don't support this extension, so they report such certificate as untrusted.

Comment: You can solve the *incomplete certificate chain* issue manually by concatenating all certificates from the certificate to the trusted root certificate (exclusive, in this order), to prevent such issues. Note, the trusted root certificate should not be there, as it is already included in the system’s root certificate store.

Comment: You should be able to fetch intermediate certificates from the issuer and concat them together by yourself. I have written a script to automate the procedure, it loops over the AIA extension to produce output of correctly chained certificates. https://github.com/zakjan/cert-chain-resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the fact that your desktop and your phone may have different set of trusted CAs, your certificate chain is incomplete (according the the [Qualys SSL Labs test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)): there must be something wrong with the content of the file used by `SSLCertificateChainFile`. You should include all intermediate certificates and in the right order.

Comment: Note that you could fix your cipher suite configuration too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it really helped me to solve the issue - the intermediate cert had somehow got corrupted so just re-installed it and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess would be that the two browsers have different Trusted Root CA lists and that the issuer is included in the desktop's certificate store but is not included in the store on the Android device.

Bottom line, the server is likely configured properly  and this is most a client side issue that you will either have to add the issuing CA to the trusted list on the failing clients or get a certificate from a different provider that is trusted by your client base.

Comment: Thanks David good basic info explained simply which is what I needed!